# linux 19.1 mint Wifi not working thinkpad e580

Tags: linux-mint, wifi, drivers, thinkpad

I just installed Linux mint in this machine and wireless connection is not working out of the box. You can find more information below:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 30 Apr 2019 14:50 AEST +1000

Booted last: 30 Apr 2019 00:00 AEST +1000

Script from: 22 Oct 2018 03:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: LinuxMint
Description:    Linux Mint 19.1 Tessa
Release:    19.1
Codename:   tessa

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.15.0-20-generic #21-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 24 06:16:15 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=1

##### desktop ###########################

Cinnamon

##### lspci #############################

03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [17aa:5068]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:b822]
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:b023]
    Kernel modules: r8822be

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 06cb:00a2 Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 5986:2113 Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:b023 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### secure boot #######################

SecureBoot enabled

##### lsmod #############################

mac80211              778240  0
cfg80211              622592  1 mac80211
intel_wmi_thunderbolt    16384  0
wmi_bmof               16384  0
wmi                    24576  2 wmi_bmof,intel_wmi_thunderbolt

##### interfaces ########################

[/etc/network/interfaces]
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback <MAC address> brd <MAC address>
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'enp3s0' [IF1]> brd <MAC address>
    inet 192.168.1.108/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp3s0
       valid_lft 604321sec preferred_lft 604321sec
    inet6 fe80::ca0c:476f:b4a9:ae4d/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

##### iwconfig ##########################

enp3s0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp3s0 proto dhcp metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp3s0 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp3s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.108 metric 100 

##### resolv.conf #######################

[777 root '/etc/resolv.conf' -> '../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf']

nameserver 127.0.0.53

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       822     1  0 14:32 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp3s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3LK-NAPI
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               --
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp3s0' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:03:00.0/net/enp3s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enp3s0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 1
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       69731fb2-585a-3d28-a544-fafa54a3f532
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     100 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.1.108/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.1.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.1.1, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 192.168.1.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             1.1.1.1
IP4.DNS[2]:                             1.0.0.1
IP4.WINS[1]:                            192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       next_server = 0.0.0.0
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       broadcast_address = 192.168.1.255
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       ip_address = 192.168.1.108
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       routers = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       domain_name_servers = 1.1.1.1 1.0.0.1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       netbios_name_servers = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 604800
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       network_number = 192.168.1.0
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       expiry = 1557204171
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.1.1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::ca0c:476f:b4a9:ae4d/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = ff00::/8, nh = ::, mt = 256, table=255
IP6.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 256
IP6.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 100
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{2}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   69731fb2-585a-3d28-a544-fafa54a3f532 | Wired connection 1

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager config #############

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3

[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=false
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-dns-resolved.conf]]
[main]
dns=systemd-resolved

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf]]
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:wwan

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf]]
[connectivity]
uri=http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com/

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]]
[device-mac-addr-change-wifi]
match-device=driver:rtl8723bs,driver:rtl8189es,driver:r8188eu,driver:8188eu,driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
wifi.cloned-mac-address=preserve
ethernet.cloned-mac-address=preserve

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Wi-Fi connection 1]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Wi-Fi connection 1 | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Home
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### Netplan config ####################

[/etc/netplan/1-network-manager-all.yaml]
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Australia/Brisbane (based on set time zone)

global
country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

enp3s0    no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

enp3s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-20-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     1CEA5CF286EDB289C1D0BF8
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           mac80211
vermagic:       4.15.0-20-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-20-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     D5B0789D4C423C81CCFB437
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           cfg80211
vermagic:       4.15.0-20-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

########## wireless info END ############
```

Edit1: It looks like the problem is the missing wireless driver (Realtek RTL8822BE). Also I found [this repository](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/drivers/staging/rtlwifi/rtl8822be) that may have the necessary files but I still don't know that to do with them.

Edit 2 : I tried to follow these steps bellow found in stackoverflow.

```
sudo apt install build-essential git
git clone https://github.com/rtlwifi-linux/rtlwifi-next
cd rtlwifi-next
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe rtl8822be
```

But I got this error:

> CC [M]  /home/MYUSER/Downloads/rtlwifi-next/base.o
>   /home/MYUSER/Downloads/rtlwifi-next/base.c: In function
>   ‘_rtl_init_deferred_work’:
>   /home/MYUSER/Downloads/rtlwifi-next/base.c:460:2: error: implicit
>   declaration of function ‘setup_timer’; did you mean ‘sk_stop_timer’?
>   [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
>   setup_timer(&rtlpriv->works.watchdog_timer,   ^~~~~~~~~~~
>   sk_stop_timer

EDIT 3: After I posted my answer I enabled my Secure Boot and my wifi stopped working. Thus, my wifi is only working when my Secure Boot is disabled.

Comment: It looks like `enp3s0` is a wired connection, I cannot see any device in your post that looks like a wireless device.  What hardware is your wireless device?  Have you checked if your wireless hardware requires drivers or software not included in a default install?

Comment: I found out the problem. This Realtek RTL8822BE driver is missing.

Comment: I tried. but when I run sudo make, I got this latest error that I just wrote. Maybe is because of my kernel version? I tried to updated but didn't worked.

Comment: You also have an 4.15 kernel, see this [comment](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/issues/318#issuecomment-363190152).
There is an `extended` branch in this repo which is said to be working. You can clone it with `git clone -b extended https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git`, 
change directory with `cd rtlwifi_new`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternate answer you could sign the drivers with the MOK Key

The full write up is [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/SecureBoot)

This way you can keep secure boot enabled!

Writing up the basis of it all from downloading the repo to finish would look like this:

(Note I signed more modules then I probably needed to. I'm not sure which ones govern what except rtl8822be was my driver so I signed all of them without rtl in front just in case.)

```
#Generate a new MOK key
sudo update-secureboot-policy --new-key
#Enroll key into firmware
sudo update-secureboot-policy --enroll-key
```

**Read the instructions from enroll key.**
**Reboot your computer and follow them.**

Next part is the same as before:

```
sudo apt install build-essential git
git clone -b extended https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
cd rtlwifi_new
make
```

Here comes the fun part:

```
sudo kmodsign sha512  \
/var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv \
/var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der  \
rtl_pci.ko

sudo kmodsign sha512  \
/var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv \
/var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der  \
rtlwifi.ko

sudo kmodsign sha512  \
/var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv \
/var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der  \
rtl8822be/rtl8822be.ko
```

After that we finish up the same way

```
sudo make install
sudo modprobe rtl8822be
```

Then voila wifi is working.

Answer (score 1):

After a fresh install of Linux Mint my wifi was not working duo to a missing driver Realtek RTL8822BE.

To install I had to follow these steps:

```
sudo apt install build-essential git
git clone -b extended https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
cd rtlwifi_new
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe rtl8822be
```

Note that I am cloning the extended branch because of my version of kernel 4.15 as @Freddy pointed.

After `sudo modprobe rtl8822be` I got these following error:

> modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'rtl8822be': Required key not
>   available

Then I needed to disable Secure Boot, you can achieve that in many ways as [this links](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762254/why-do-i-get-required-key-not-available-when-install-3rd-party-kernel-modules) pointed. But what worked for me was [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/808105). You need to follow each step of this answers to get the correct results.

Finally I runned `sudo mobprobe rtl882be` and got this output on console:

> modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'rtl8822be': Exec format error

Then I realized that my wifi was already working.